# Resilience4J retryOnException not working

Tags: java, kotlin, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

Retry on exception is not working for Resilience4j 1.7.

Can anyone else confirm? At this point I'm just writing simple tests to try this without success.

I also submitted a ticket here: https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/1886

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/1886

An answer from the repo: we need to use the following methods to work on checked exceptions:

- decorateCallable()
- executeCallable()

Confirmed that this worked for us.